# Highstock error #16 with Spring Boot/Thymeleaf app

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, highcharts

I am working on a Spring Boot/Thymeleaf app and am wanting to insert a highstock chart (for [Compare Multiple Series](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare)). I had it working the other day, but when trying to load now, I get error #16 which, of course, states

> **Highcharts already defined in the page**
>
> This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js file.

The trouble is, though, that I basically copied the code directly from the chart's jsfiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/) with only a few basic changes.

- The javascript part of the code has been added to its own .js file named trendGraph.js.
- The script imports have been added to my _header.html fragment, along with the import of the trendChart.js file.
- The div tag has been added to the actual buy.html page where I want the chart to display (but I have changed the id from "container" to "trendGraphContainer" in this div tag as well as the corresponding place in the trendGraph.js file).

I can not for the life of me figure out where the problem is coming in, as I am only loading one chart, and I have no duplicated code that I can find. Other answers on stackoverflow have not solved my problem, and I have read at least 10 or more questions regarding Highcharts and error #16.

Here is my code below:

**trendGraph.js**

```
/**
* 
*/

var seriesOptions = [],
seriesCounter = 0,
names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

/**
* Create the chart when all data is loaded
* @returns {undefined}
*/
function createChart() {

Highcharts.stockChart('trendGraphContainer', {

rangeSelector: {
  selected: 4
},

yAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
    }
  },
  plotLines: [{
    value: 0,
    width: 2,
    color: 'silver'
  }]
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    compare: 'percent',
    showInNavigator: true
  }
},

tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b> 
  {point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
  valueDecimals: 2,
  split: true
},

series: seriesOptions
});
}

$.each(names, function (i, name) {

  $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json',  function (data) {

    seriesOptions[i] = {
      name: name,
      data: data
    };

    // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
   // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
seriesCounter += 1;

   if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
     createChart();
   }
  });
});
```

**_header.html**

```
<!-- HighCharts js for pricing trend graph -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/trendGraph.js"></script>
```

**buy.html**

```
<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-6 mb-4 mb-xl-0">
    <div class="card shadow">
        <div id="card-header" class="card-header">
            <h6 class="h6 text-uppercase mb-0 d-inline">Pricing Trends</h6>
                <div id="trendGraphContainer" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
        </div> <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div> <!-- /.card -->
</div> <!-- /.row mb-4 -->
```

Thank you for your time and I greatly appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Hi @Krista, Perhaps `_header.html` file is double loaded? The code from all your files works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ltdv5okn/ Please try to remove the `highstock` script from the file `_header.html`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried removing the <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script> from the _header but it didn't work. Since you said it may be possibly loaded twice, I then thought maybe since the _header is called by more than one page it may the issue, so I tried removing all of the script imports from the _header and moved them directly to buy.html, but that didn't work either :(.

Comment: Hi Krista, I do not knot how you exactly load your files, but the problem is definitely caused by multiple loading Highcharts script. Is the same error showing after removing the script?

Comment: OK, a coworker finally found the error for me, and I feel so incredibly stupid, as it was of course something easy: when we first toyed with the idea of including the highcharts into the app, I had added the highcharts import to my _include.html file. We hadn't touched highcharts since, so I had completely forgotten. Of course, it was now in both _include.html and _header.html. So I got rid of that error, but I still have a CORs error, which I am not concerned about because we will not need that for getting our own data. Thank you so much and sorry to bother you!